# Just for fun coding

Tags: complex-numbers

For Fun!

From standard input, read two pairs of doubles and create two complex number of those numbers (first two doubles form first complex number and second two numbers forms second complex number, first number in each pair is real part of complex number), then compute and print out the result of angle, difference (first - second), conjugate (of first number), dividision (first / second), power2 (first to power 2), and power3(first to power 3).

double theta(): computes the angle of this complex number.

Complex minus(Complex b): returns a complex number that is equal to the difference of this complex number and the argument(b)

Complex conjugate(): returns the conjugate of this complex number as a new complex number

Complex divides(Complex b): returns the division result of this number by the argument(b)

Complex power(int b): returns the result of raising this number to the bth power.

Complex squareRoot(): returns the result of the square root operation as a complex number

Comment: Have you tried something? that question looks like you want the community give you an answer without trying... or if that is just some kind of "game to the community" then it should be closed... I do not want to be rude, it's just my appreciation of your question

Comment: I can post my code for it, but I am new on here. Would you like to see mine? Just tell me how. Just thought it would be something fun to do. Not looking for answers. Had fun doing it because Complex numbers aren't something used to be doing.

Comment: How do I close it?